# How can I make import dependent on ios version in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a framework that I want to import and use only on ios13 and above. How can I conditionally use this framework? The canImport method didn't work successfully for me and kept giving errors at compile time. Does anyone have a suggestion for this situation?

"canImport doesn't seem to consider the OS version and I couldn't find any other solution for this issue."

Comment: `#canImport` is for conditional *compilation*. For conditionally *running* code, you should always import the framework, and use `@available` to check the iOS version.

Comment: @Sweeper Since I will be doing this check while importing a framework, don't I still need to do it at compile time? I thought that if I can perform an OS check with #if os(), I should also be able to perform a version check for the OS.

Comment: No, you seem to be confused. You can only do this check at runtime. At compile time, the app isn't even on the user's device yet. It is simply impossible to check the user's OS version.

Comment: @Sweeper I guess there is no method for what I want, thank you.